# Flutter stopwatchtimer doesn't respond to changing time

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, package

I use this package https://pub.dev/packages/stop_watch_timer in my app to keep track of the music that is playing. However if I want to change the song by changing the time on the stopwatch it says that I have to reset the timer first which I have already done. If I press the button for the second time it works. This is the code:

```dart
  final StopWatchTimer _stopWatchTimer = StopWatchTimer(
    mode: StopWatchMode.countUp,
    onChangeRawSecond: (value) => print('onChangeRawSecond $value'),
  );



  void change_timer_value(int song_index) {
    int new_time = TimerState(
            song_index: song_index,
            record_side: current_side_list(
                record_sides[selectedValue], widget.album_data))
        .get_start_value();
    print(new_time);

    _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.reset);
    _stopWatchTimer.setPresetSecondTime(new_time); // this is where I set new time
  }
```

I don't know how to get around this. I have already created an issue on the creators GitHub but no response. So there's somebody who can help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the github issue, it looks like the root cause of your issue is that the reset action takes place asynchronously, and so hasn't gone through yet by the time you try to set the time.

One way to get around this is to define your own async function which resets the stopwatch, then waits for the action to complete before returning:

```
Future<void> _resetTimer() {
  final completer = Completer<void>();

  // Create a listener that will trigger the completer when
  // it detects a reset event.
  void listener(StopWatchExecute event) {
    if (event == StopWatchExecute.reset) {
      completer.complete();
    }
  }

  // Add the listener to the timer's execution stream, saving
  // the sub for cancellation
  final sub = _stopWatchTimer.execute.listen(listener);

  // Send the 'reset' action
  _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.reset);

  // Cancel the sub after the future is fulfilled.
  return completer.future.whenComplete(sub.cancel);
}
```

Usage:

```
void change_timer_value(int song_index) {
  int new_time = TimerState(
          song_index: song_index,
          record_side: current_side_list(
              record_sides[selectedValue], widget.album_data))
      .get_start_value();
  print(new_time);

  _resetTimer().then(() {
    _stopWatchTimer.setPresetSecondTime(new_time);
  });
}
```

Or (with async/await):

```
void change_timer_value(int song_index) async {
  int new_time = TimerState(
          song_index: song_index,
          record_side: current_side_list(
              record_sides[selectedValue], widget.album_data))
      .get_start_value();
  print(new_time);

  await _resetTimer();
  _stopWatchTimer.setPresetSecondTime(new_time);
}
```